# Change size of R output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

I'm preparing a beamer presentation using RMarkdown and want to include `lm` output in it. However the default size is too large, therefore the output is clipped and can't be seen entirely. How can I change the options to control the size (or font) of R output? I have seen plenty of options regarding size of plots, but none with regards to R output.

Comment: Something like this? http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/rmarkdown-and-font-size-td4736865.html

Comment: I've been trying to change many of these style options, but neither of them seems to work.

Comment: @jakes Could you give me please some feedback whether my answer below has solved your problem?

Answer (score 13):

Rmarkdown's beamer presentation works with `LaTeX` code. To change the output size you can use the corresponding `LaTeX` commands, set just before the code junk. The smallest option would be `\tiny`. For a full overview consider e.g. [this](http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-font-size.html). After the code junk it's important to set back to the size you used before, e.g. `\normalsize`.

***Example***

````
---
output: beamer_presentation
---

# Regression
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\tiny
```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(lm(speed ~ dist, cars))
```

\normalsize
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
````

***Yielding***

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `output:powerpoint_presentation`. Any idea for that?

Comment: @drj3122 Since I don't work with MS office I have no clue. What I know is that power point doesn't use LaTeX. You could ask this as a new question and refer to this one.