# Changing font of code output rmarkdown pdf - saving space

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm making a rmarkdown document with pdf output (using rstudio), and I would like to change the font of the code output (I would take a font that take less space than the default one).

Here is a screen shot of an output : [image]

With another font I could divide this in 2 and print it using the whole width and less height.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51230579/6574038 ?

Comment: It's interresting to have this in mind, thanks. But what I found the best is to use kable function, which use a different font with also the possibiy to change fontsize.

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?